# How to text buy signals due to its close value instead of writing down 'BUY'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I just want to write it down with numbers(due to its close value like 30.567) instead of saying 'BUY'.

```
plotshape(buySignalk and showsignalsk and O1 > K2 ? XXXTrend[2] * 0.9999 : na, title='BUY', text="BUY",location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(#0022FC, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Like -> title='BUY', text="BUY" --> text = str.tostring(close)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `plotshape`.

You should use [labels](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#creating-drawings) instead.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none, text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high))
```

[image]